# Sublime2 "translate_tabs_to_spaces: false" but it still inserts spaces. Why?

Tags: text, tabs, sublimetext2, spaces

So I'm using Sublime Text 2, and I have set

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
```

so that tabs remain tabs and don't get converted to spaces. However, when I type a tab, it still inserts 4 spaces, and not a tab. Does anybody know why that is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I found it just after posting. I had

`"detect_indentation": true,`

so it finds out that spaces are used instead of tabs, and will then use that instead of the default tabs.

Comment: I have it false, and it still doesn't translate tabs to spaces!

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for that.
1. Open the file
2. Select all.
3. Cut it.
4. Save file.
5. Close file.
6. Open file (It must be empty)
7. Paste it.

Thats all!.